# Unable to login through putty in Centos but able to ping to the VM

Tags: centos, ssh, putty, static-linking

I was able to login through putty until I changed the VM configuration to static ipaddress and restarted the network and rebooted the VM

I see the sshd service is running as well.
I am able to ping the VM, but unable to login through putty.
Below is the error I see:

```
login as: root
root@<hostname>'s password:
Tacacs authentication failed Access denied
```

Comment: Please check the authentication log on the VM. Add relevant entries to your question. Check the connection to and from the tacacs central server and add that info.

Comment: There is no tacacs central server as such.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search shows that tacacs requires a central authentication server. Is the VM still able to communicate with that server with it's new network configuration?
Perhaps you need to update the tacacs configuration either on the VM or on the central server?

If you do not want the system to use tacacs at all you will need to check and change the Pam configuration.

Check the security log on the system and check the Pam and possibly the sshd configuration.

Comment: I have provisioned the VM using vCenter Server. I am not understanding what you mean by central authentication server. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The error message you posted says that the tacacs authentication failed. If that is not what you expect and you have not configured such authentication that might explain why you can't log on.